# Powershell - calling unmanaged Function CreateProfile crashes Powershell.exe

Tags: powershell, pinvoke, unmanaged

When calling a unmanaged piece of code with [pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/userenv/CreateProfile.html) -- [createprofile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762271(v=vs.85).aspx).  The Powershell.exe process crashes after the call to the method in the unmanaged code. The profile is created successfully.

Why this would happen?  My code is below:

```
    function CreateProfile
    {
        param([String]$UserSid, [String]$UserName,  [system.uint32]$ProfilePath)
        Add-Type -TypeDefinition '
            using System;
            using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
            public static class PInvoke {
                [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
                public static extern int CreateProfile( [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String pszUserSid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String pszUserName, [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] System.Text.StringBuilder pszProfilePath, uint cchProfilePath);
            }
        '
       $pszProfilePath = new-object -typename System.Text.StringBuilder
    [int]$results = [PInvoke]::CreateProfile($UserSid, $UserName, $pszProfilePath, $ProfilePath)
    }
$stringbuff = new-object system.text.stringbuilder(260)
[system.uint32]$a =$stringbuff.capacity
$sid = ((get-aduser -id 'brtestlocaluser').sid.value)
CreateProfile -usersid $sid -username 'brtestlocaluser' -ProfilePath $a
```

Comment: you can omit the code with try catch blocks and output the logs or try to debug the code in ISE to see where it fails. do some investigation by yourself first.

Comment: You pass just created `StringBuilder` (`Capacity` = 0) in third parameter of `CreateProfile` and 260 in fourth parameter of `CreateProfile`. Since actuall capacity (0) is less then declared capacity (260), `CreateProfile` is corrupting the memory and causing process crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to figure this out. Calling it in another means seemed to fix this issue.

```
function Register-NativeMethod
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        [string]$dll,

        # Param2 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=1)]
        [string]
        $methodSignature
    )

    $script:nativeMethods += [PSCustomObject]@{ Dll = $dll; Signature = $methodSignature; }
}
function Add-NativeMethods
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param($typeName = 'NativeMethods')

    $nativeMethodsCode = $script:nativeMethods | ForEach-Object { "
        [DllImport(`"$($_.Dll)`")]
        public static extern $($_.Signature);
    " }

    Add-Type @"
        using System;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
        public static class $typeName {
            $nativeMethodsCode
        }
"@
}
function New-ProfileFromSID {

[CmdletBinding()]
[Alias()]
[OutputType([int])]
Param
(
    # Param1 help description
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
               Position=0)]
    [string]$UserName,
    [string]$domain = ''
)
$methodname = 'UserEnvCP2'
$script:nativeMethods = @();

if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]$methodname).Type)
{
    Register-NativeMethod "userenv.dll" "int CreateProfile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszUserSid,`
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszUserName,`
     [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszProfilePath, uint cchProfilePath)";

    Add-NativeMethods -typeName $methodname;
}

$sb = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder(260);
$pathLen = $sb.Capacity;

Write-Verbose "Creating user profile for $Username";
#$SID= ((get-aduser -id $UserName -ErrorAction Stop).sid.value)
if($domain)
{
    $objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($domain, $UserName)
    $strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
    $SID = $strSID.Value
}
else 
{
   $objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($UserName)
   $strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
   $SID = $strSID.Value
}
Write-Verbose "$UserName SID: $SID"
try
{
   $result = [UserEnvCP2]::CreateProfile($SID, $Username, $sb, $pathLen) 
   if($result -eq '-2147024713')
   {
       $status = "$userName already exists"
       write-verbose "$username Creation Result: $result"
    }
    elseif($result -eq '-2147024809')
    {
        $status = "$username Not Found"
        write-verbose "$username creation result: $result"
    }
   elseif($result -eq 0)
   {
       $status = "$username Profile has been created"
       write-verbose "$username Creation Result: $result"
   }
   else
   {
      $status = "$UserName unknown return result: $result"
   }
}
catch
{
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message;
    break;
}
$status
}
```